# List of names of models in a Backbone.js Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to learn a little bit of backbone.js and I'm getting stuck on something I think should be fairly simple to figure out. How do I get a list of all model names in a collection?

I'm even copy+pasting from the backbone tutorial:

```
var Song = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "Not specified",
        artist: "Not specified"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Music is the answer");
    }
});

var Album = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Song
});

var song1 = new Song({ name: "How Bizarre", artist: "OMC" });
var song2 = new Song({ name: "Sexual Healing", artist: "Marvin Gaye" });
var song3 = new Song({ name: "Talk It Over In Bed", artist: "OMC" });

var myAlbum = new Album([ song1, song2, song3]);
console.log( myAlbum.models ); // [song1, song2, song3]
```

The problem is - this doesn't give me model names in the console:
   console.log( myAlbum.models ); // [song1, song2, song3]
instead I get [child, child, child, child] - how do I get the actual names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `pluck` the `name` attribute.

```
myAlbum.pluck('name');
```

There is no way to get an array like this:

```
['song1', 'song2', 'song3']
```

because names of variables are not available in program logic.

#### Update

When the tutorial writes this:

```
console.log( myAlbum.models ); // [song1, song2, song3]
```

It means that the array `models` is the same as if you were to write `[song1, song2, song3]`, not as if you were to write `['song1', 'song2', 'song3']`. The quotes are the differentiating factor.

Comment: Thanks Logan, that gives me all the 'name' attributes - but I'm looking for the model names.. in the tutorial: http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection/  the collection is created with models  song1, song2 and song3. I want to get a list of all models in the collection and I thought collection.models would do that..

Comment: @Henry What do you mean 'name'? Like you want an array with the strings 'song1', 'song2', 'song3' in it? What you have printed in your question IS an array of model objects, it just gets printed as 'child'. As in `myAlbum.models[0] === song1`

Comment: Yep, how do I print an array with just 'song1', 'song2' etc.. sorry I'm not even asking this properly :)

Comment: @Henry The names of variables are not available as strings in your code. Can you explain why you want to access them? Maybe I can give another suggestion.

Comment: Sure, I was just following the tutorial backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-collection  and I thought I was doing something wrong because the tutorial makes it seem like should..  my end goal was to understand how removing models works.. I figure if I can get the model names in strings i can then remove individual models using names as the unique identifier. maybe i should be looking at cid?

Comment: @Henry Ohh, got it. I updated my answer to be a bit more descriptive.